# Multiple Radio Button Groups With Same Name

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have been passed down a complex application which dynamically creates HTML.

The problem is, the previous person did not know that the "name" attribute of radio buttons actually is the group association.

With the following mark up, is there any way to put these in two groups

```
<div>
  <%-- would like this to be a seperate group without changing name--%>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Group 1 Option 1</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Group 1 Option 2</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Group 1 Option 3</label>
</div>

<div>
  <%-- would like this to be a seperate group without changing name--%>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Group 2 Option 1</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Group 2 Option 2</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Group 2 Option 3</label>
</div>
```

Is there any div or anything I can wrap around them to separate the grouping? I have tried field set and legend but it has no effect. I know I could put each one in a form but then they will not all be submitted.

Comment: You'll need to give different names to each grouping of radio buttons.

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock That is my only option?

Comment: Yes, assuming you want to be able to check an item from each grouping.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Put them in different form tag

```
<form>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Group 1 Option 1</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Group 1 Option 2</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Group 1 Option 3</label>
</form>

<form>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Group 2 Option 1</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Group 2 Option 2</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Group 2 Option 3</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I’m unsure as to why you couldn’t use the array association, like name=“radio[]” ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: if wrap your radios with `label for="..."` this may not work.

Comment: `label for="..."` need to set diff id.

Answer (score 1):

from my knowledge, you cant. the name of the radio button defines the group it is in, then in the handler for the submitted form, you call the name to get the selected option. using line separators or divs will not disassociate them with each other. you can only have one radio button for a group selected. if you only want them visually separated, Austin has the right idea.

Changing the name of each individual group is your only option to allow 2 selected buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for something like that too, a bit later :D

```
<input type="radio" name="radio[group1]" value="0" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio[group1]" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="radio[group1]" value="2">

<input type="radio" name="radio[group2]" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="radio[group2]" value="1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio[group2]" value="2">
```

In your form result, you'll have :

```
"radio" => [
    "group1" => "0",
    "group2" => "1"
]
```

Comment: This is only valid for PHP. Whether the result will be structured as you present depends on your back-end. By default, the client-side JavaScript will not structure the FormData this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert them a checkbox and wrap with an element (ex:fieldset) and write small jquery code for if checked any checkbox then uncheck other checkboxes in same fieldset.

I had faced the same issue. In a form, multiple products needed to be added to the same user, but there was a radio button for selecting an option in the product properties. When the user clicked on the "+1 product" button, a new product field was generated. Since they all had the same name attribute, they conflicted with each other.

The name attribute of my radio elements was as follows: shape_type[]

I found the solution by converting my radio elements into checkboxes.

convert radiobox elements to checkbox and wrap with fieldset and just paste the code.

```
    // if any checkbox changed set not changed in same fieldset
        $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
            $(this).parents('fieldset').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
```

If you want it to work exactly like radio buttons, where you cannot deselect the selected option, you can try the following code:

```
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
            $(this).parents('fieldset').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            if($(this).parents('fieldset').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0){
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -7):

I think you want to use `<fieldset>`, this will allow you to separate them within the same form.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ndn7jmh5/2/

If you can't do that try using `<br/>` to separate them onto different lines.

Comment: Both groups still behave as one big group.

Comment: @clamchoda If you want to be able to tick an option from each group you need to change the name. Otherwise you would be submitting two values within the same post. It just wouldn't work.