# How can I make multiple radio button groups with same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

My code like this :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>England</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Chelsea
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Mu
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Arsenal
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Spain</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Madrid
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Barcelona
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Atletico
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Demos like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/m7by6zcw/1/

I want to use the same name on both groups button like my code above. But the impact is that both radio button groups can only choose one. There are cases that make me have to use the same name.

How to make both groups button can be selected even though using the same name?

Comment: You May Use Different Form Tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Radio Button Groups With Same Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791791/multiple-radio-button-groups-with-same-name)

Comment: Put them in different form tag

Comment: Is there no other way? Because when adding the form, it makes my appearance becomes untidy

Comment: @AdhershMNair, I see the link, there is an answer that uses this `<div class="col-md-6">`. In my html, I use this : `<div class="col-md-4">`. But why it does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your radio button groups in separate `form` tags like this. Only one `name` group can be present in one form.

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>England</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Chelsea
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Mu
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Arsenal
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Spain</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Madrid
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Barcelona
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Atletico
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no other way? Because when adding the form, it makes my appearance becomes untidy

Comment: If adding `<form>` tag distorting your UI, you can change your CSS accordingly. It may be possible that you have applied your CSS and using the <form> tag distorting the hierarchy of your nested code.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Bind your radio button groups in two forms that will allow you to select them independently. Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/m7by6zcw/5/

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>England</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Chelsea
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Mu
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Arsenal
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<form>


    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Spain</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Madrid
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Barcelona
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="test"> Atletico
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no other way? Because when adding the form, it makes my appearance becomes untidy

Comment: Adding form tag does not change your appearence may be you had any unclosed tag

Comment: It made my appearance untidy. Which I show in jsfiddle, it's not my original view. I do not show my real view. It's only my simple view

Comment: In that case I can't help you now as I busy with some other work

Comment: Okay. No problem. Thanks for your help